# Symbolic integration with Python

Tags: python, calculus

I'd like to compute a distribution in a symbolic way with Python.
The distribution is

```
f(z) = \frac{1}{(b-a)^2}\int^b_a z\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}(zw)dw
```

How to compute  this integral knowing that

```
[a,b]\bigcap [a/z,b/z] \neq \emptyset
```

Comment: Is `{[a,b]}` in the denominator a typo?

Comment: No i just write the expression in Latex.